# SQL - Is this allowed?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, I have a merge statement. Is the WHERE clause valid after the WHEN MATCHED statement or is there another way to do this?

```
MERGE dbo.MyTable AS TARGET 
USING (select * from dbo.StageTable)

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATED SET target.[Col1] = source.[Col1] WHERE [Col1] <> "StartTime"
```

Also, is it possible to use a SELECT statement instead of the source.Column.... The real issue I'm having is that I don't know what column the data I require will be in on the StageTable... The only thing I do know is that it contains the text "StartTime" somewhere in the column.

Comment: No. You need to put your condition on the `WHEN MATCHED` clause - e.g. `WHEN MATCHED AND [Col1] <> 'StartTime' THEN UPDATE set target.[Col1] = source.[Col1]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if `MATCH` works without an `ON` clause, maybe by matching rows using primary keys of the two tables, but you'd probably be better of by using a more explicit syntax.

The following `MERGE` will try to match all rows that have the same value in `Id`, but only if the value in `Col1` is *not* "StartTime".

```
MERGE dbo.MyTable AS TARGET 
USING (select * from dbo.StageTable) AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.Id = SOURCE.Id AND SOURCE.Col1 <> "StartTime")
WHEN MATCHED
UPDATED SET TARGET.Col1 = SOURCE.Col1
```

This obviously means that you are required to provide an `Id` column, which should be present in every table anyway.

It's almost always better to put your matching logic in the ON clause.